# While loop suddenly stop mining during Beautiful Soup but the process continues endless?

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, while-loop, python-requests

I'm creating a template for web scraping news using Selenium and Beautiful Soup.

I've created a DataFrame with a column with all the links I want to **scrape** from a website I chose to test. I achieved to isolate `post id, date, author, title, subtitle and text`.

Now I'm trying to loop through my url column and fill the other empty columns (`post id, date, author, title, subtitle and text`) with each value for each row.

I achieved to do a test for `100 rows` and it worked perfectly. But if I try with all rows (`41327`) Jupyter Notebook simply stop mining (as I can check with `TQDM`) but the process isn't interrupted. I don't know if the website is blocking me (wouldn't I get an error?), I think this is not the issue, since if I rerun the code it immediately works again until it happens the same.

Is it something with my code?

The function I've created and I'm using to web **scrape**:

```
def full_table():
    j=0
    while tqdm(j<=41327):
        try:
            url = df[0][j]
            response = requests.get(url)
            html = response.content
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser') 
            corpus  = (soup.find("article")).findAll('p')
            title = soup.find_all('h1')[1].text
            df['title'].iloc[j] = title
            subtitle = soup.find_all('h2')[0].text
            df['subtitle'].iloc[j] = subtitle
            date = soup.find(class_="author").find_all("span")[-1].get_text(strip=True)
            df['date'].iloc[j] = date
            author = soup.find(class_="author").span.get_text(strip=True)
            df['author'].iloc[j] = author
            news_id  = (soup.find("article"))["id"]
            df['news_id'].iloc[j] = news_id
            text = article(corpus)
            df['text'].iloc[j] = text          
            j+=1
        #print(df)
        except:
            j+=1
            pass
    print(df)
    return df
```

The last thing I get from TQDM is:

```
0it [00:00, ?it/s]
0it [00:13, ?it/s]
0it [00:00, ?it/s]
```

This `00:13` is the odd one, all before are the same and, as I said, if I try with `100 rows` I get a perfect DataFrame with what I need. Now I need to get all `41327` rows.

Any help I will be grateful!

Comment: Can be multiple reasons. Usually fixed with a simple ```sleep(5)```

Comment: I see. But doesn't it have a faster way? If I put 5 seconds of sleep for 41327 rows it will take 57 hours. Do you think that's the issue and that's the better way to deal with it? If it's that I will do it, of course! Thank you for you comment!

Comment: What if I try to put timeout=10 ?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `timeout=10` on our request solved the problem.

```
def full_table():
    j=0
    while tqdm(j<=41327):
        try:
            url = df[0][j]
            response = requests.get(url, timeout=10)
            html = response.content
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser') 
            corpus  = (soup.find("article")).findAll('p')
            title = soup.find_all('h1')[1].text
            df['title'].iloc[j] = title
            subtitle = soup.find_all('h2')[0].text
            df['subtitle'].iloc[j] = subtitle
            date = soup.find(class_="author").find_all("span")[-1].get_text(strip=True)
            df['date'].iloc[j] = date
            author = soup.find(class_="author").span.get_text(strip=True)
            df['author'].iloc[j] = author
            news_id  = (soup.find("article"))["id"]
            df['news_id'].iloc[j] = news_id
            text = article(corpus)
            df['text'].iloc[j] = text          
            j+=1
        #print(df)
        except:
            j+=1
            pass
    print(df)
    return df
```